# Power button isn't working as it supposed to

Tags: windows-vista, power-management, hibernate

I have a laptop which runs Windows Vista Ultimate, SP2.

I've changed the settings of the power button to always hibernate. However, when working onbattery, rather than AC power, and press the power button, the laptop sleeps, rather than hibernating.

I've checked the advanced settings of the power mode which I use when using the computer on battery, which is "Power saver" and it says "Power button action on battery is hibernate"

[image: Power button action on battery is hibernate]

Any tips on how to get it work? Thanks.

Comment: Your image is broken. Do you happen to have the original that you could reupload? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of the option box, you can see you're changing settings for the "Power Saver" power mode. Some laptops automatically switch modes when they're plugged in (mine's set to be in High Power when it's plugged in).

Make sure you're setting the "On Battery" and "Plugged In" settings for each power mode.

Comment: Thanks, actually, this is the issue. I didn't notice, at first, that the laptop has an additional 'hidden' power mode that runs automatically when the battery level is low, and that has different settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [article](http://techwhimsy.com/fixing-hibernate-problems-in-windows-vista).

> Sometimes the hibernation option is
>   not available, or your hardware key
>   combination (on my Dell it is Fn ->
>   F1) simply does not work. The first
>   thing you need to check if your
>   computer supports one of the
>   hibernation options. To do this, go to
>   the start menu and type Command in the
>   search box. In the results, right
>   click and select “Run as
>   Administrator”. When the command
>   prompt opens up, type powercfg -a
>   which shows you all of the available
>   types of hibernation that your
>   hardware supports. In the video below
>   you will notice that my laptop
>   supports s(3) which is the “deep
>   hibernation” that saves the state of
>   the system to disk before shutting the
>   hardware down.
>
> If your hardware does support
>   hibernation but it still stubbornly
>   refuses to bunker down for the winter,
>   either the hibernation option has been
>   disabled or the Hibernation File
>   Cleaner has been deleted by the Disk
>   Cleanup Utility. Both these options
>   are easily fixed using the powercfg
>   utility again. To turn hibernation
>   back on, type powercfg -h on.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've already read those tips somewhere else, and they didn't work.

Comment: Kind of a harsh -1 isn't it? You never mentioned in your question that you tried those tips. We aren't mind readers.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I'm NOT the one who downvoted your answer.

Comment: To prove that, I've just up-voted it, the system would not allow me to change my vote after this period of time.